# Scroll left/right with Buttons in Blazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have a few images in one row. Not all images can be seen. By scrolling to the right it would be possible to see the other images. I want to scroll to the right by clicking a button. How do I write my method `ScrollRight` to achieve my goal?

```
<div style="display:flex;">
    <button @onclick="ScrollLeft">A</button>
    <div style="overflow:hidden;">
        <div style="display:flex;position:relative;bottom:-30px;overflow-y:auto;">
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <img width="300" height="300" src="https://www.dogstrust.org.uk/help-advice/_images/164742v800_puppy-1.jpg" />
            <!-->and so on/!-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <button @onclick="ScrollRight">B</button>
</div>


@code {

    public void ScrollLeft()
    {

    }

    public void ScrollRight()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: use something like this in the style of the inner div - transform: translateX(@position) , and modify @position by the correct amount + or - in your click handlers to scroll each way. add a transition to make it  smooth.

Comment: @MisterMagoo I tried this but sadly it does not work. It moves the div with the visible images to the left/right but it does not reveal the images that can only be seen by scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

I created a .js file:

```
function ScrollRight(Element, Width) {
    document.getElementById(Element).scrollBy({
        top: 0, left: Width * Math.floor((document.getElementById(Element).offsetWidth / Width)), behavior: "smooth"
    })
}
function ScrollLeft(Element, Width) {
    document.getElementById(Element).scrollBy({
        top: 0, left: -Width * Math.floor((document.getElementById(Element).offsetWidth / Width)), behavior: "smooth"
    })
}
```

added `@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime` and

```
@code {


    async Task ScrollRight()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "ScrollRight", "scrollable-events", 255);
    }

    async Task ScrollLeft()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "ScrollLeft", "scrollable-events", 255);
    }

}
```

in my .razor file.

Answer (score 0):

I create the same thing and its a very easy method

1. Create a JS File with the following code

```
function myFunctionleft(id) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.scrollLeft -= 166; } function myFunctionRight(id) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.scrollLeft += 166; }
```

then
Attach your JS file in index.html (web assembly) or blazor server side in the host file

now its time to try

```
<div class="col-12">
  <button @onclick="myFunctionleft" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="oi oi-arrow-circle-left"></i></button>
  <button @onclick="myFunctionRight" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="oi oi-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
  
  <div id="@id" class="myDIV">
    <div class="contenscroll">
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        1  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bd/H2G2_UK_front_cover.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        2  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        3  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        4 <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        5 <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        6 <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        7  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        8  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>

      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        1  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bd/H2G2_UK_front_cover.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        2  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280"style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        3  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        4 <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        5 <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        6 <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        7  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>
      <div class="mydatadisplay">
        16  <img class="Myimg" alt="100%x280" style="width:144px;height:280px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532781914607-2031eca2f00d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=7c625ea379640da3ef2e24f20df7ce8d">
      </div>

    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

and put this code in your code block

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

public async Task myFunctionleft()
{
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("myFunctionleft", id);
}
public async Task myFunctionRight()
{
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("myFunctionRight", id);
}
```

Guid ID solve the duplication ID issue now you can use many components with same functionality[image]